# c.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code give me this error: `c.apply is not a function`
All code works well only if i use one function. However i am not sure about how use two functions. These lines are probably wrong :

```
 postHandler(<?php echo get_posts($db, 0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>, <?php echo get_posts1($db, 0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>);
```

and

```
var postHandler = function(postsJSON, postsJSON1) {
$.each(postsJSON, postsJSON1, function(i, post, post1) {
```

*script*

**first function**

```
function get_posts($db, $start, $number_of_posts) {
       //code
            return json_encode($posts);
        }
```

output:

```
string '[{"username":"Altitude software","foto_oferta":"thumb\/miniaturas\/oferta\/default_offer.jpg","actividades":"Some activities","id_oferta":77,"oferta":"Programador web" ...
```

**second function**

```
function get_posts1($db, $start, $number_of_posts) {
       //code
            return json_encode($posts1);
        }
```

output:

```
string '[{"id_offer":77,"tags":["c++","JAVA"]},{"id_offer":76,"tags":["ajax","php"]},{"id_offer":75,"tags":["PHP","JAVA"]}]'
```

**js**

```
var postHandler = function(postsJSON, postsJSON1) {
                $.each(postsJSON, postsJSON1, function(i, post, post1) {
                    var id = 'post-' + post.id_oferta;

                    $('<div></div>').addClass('post').attr('id',id)
                    .html('<div class="box_offers"><div class="rating_offer"></div><div class="post-title">' 
                            + post.oferta + '</div>  <div class="post-box"> <a class="oferta_val bold_username">'
                            + post1.tags + '</a></div><a id='+id+'hide class="post-more" >Descrição</a><div class="logo_offer">')
                            .appendTo($('#posts'));

                    $('#'+id+'hide').click(function() {
                        $('.'+id+'hidden').slideToggle('fast');
                    });
                }); 
            };

postHandler(<?php echo get_posts($db, 0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>, <?php echo get_posts1($db, 0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>);
```

Comment: I've posted an answer indicating why you are getting that error, but if you can update your question to give the structure of the two objects returned by your PHP (i.e., what ends up in the `postsJSON` and `postsJSON1` parameters) I can give you some code to iterate over both in parallel that should work with your existing code (I just don't want to waste time writing it based on a guess).

Comment: @nnnnnn The problem is this: I have a query that returns username, id, local, offer, and so on. But i need another function because i need to get the tags for each offer. The main problem is each offer can get many tags, so for each offer i need data from two php functions. The json output is huge to post

Comment: Post a sample of the JSON output with just a couple of rows of data in each, and indicate how they relate to each other. Your existing code implies that `postsJSON` and `postsJSON1` have properties or elements (depending on whether they're plain objects or arrays) that are one-to-one. Are they arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is this line:

```
$.each(postsJSON, postsJSON1, function(i, post, post1) {
```

The [generic iterator `$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function only takes two parameters, the second of which is supposed to be a function. Similarly the callback function you provide is supposed to take two parameters.

What is your intention as far as supplying two objects to iterate over at the same time? If you can describe your data structures and explain what you want to do I could make some suggestions. (Show your JSON...)

**UPDATE:** OK, based on the question update both `postsJSON` and `postsJSON1` are arrays. Given the way that you were trying to use both from inside the same function it appears that the elements within the arrays have a one-to-one relationship, that is, `postsJSON[0]` relates to `postsJSON1[0]`, `postsJSON[1]` relates to `postsJSON1[1]`, `postsJSON[2]` relates to `postsJSON1[2]`, and so on and so forth.

If that is the case the smallest possible change to your existing code to get it to work would be this:

```
var postHandler = function(postsJSON, postsJSON1) {
   $.each(postsJSON, function(i, post) {
      var post1 = postsJSON1[i];

      // the rest of your code from inside your $.each() here
   });
};
```

That is, continue to use `$.each()`, but noting that it can only directly iterate over one array at a time use the provided index `i` to iterate over the other array in parallel by setting that up manually as the first line of the function.

Or perhaps the more obvious way to do it is with a traditional `for` loop:

```
var postHandler = function(postsJSON, postsJSON1) {
   var i, post, post1;
   for (i = 0; i < postsJSON.length; i++) {
      post = postsJSON[i];
      post1 = postsJSON1[i];

      // the rest of your code from inside your $.each() here
   }    
};
```

Either way will process both arrays in parallel. Obviously this assumes the arrays are the same length and that the items at any given index number will be the items that you want to relate to each other as mentioned above - if not then you will need to provide more detail about how the arrays are related.

Comment: I need two different functions because i have two different queries. It Is possible pass more than one parameter ?